# RewriteRule explanation

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

Could anyone explain the following two lines please?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$   index.php?page=$1&id=$2&im=$3
```

I hope to be a detailed explanation because I do not have any idea about the .htaccess file.

any body can help me? I appreciate any suggestions ..
thank you ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteRule contains mainly 3 so call it parts:

1. `^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$` **this is the rule by which your urls are going to be rewritten**
2. `index.php?page=$1&id=$2&im=$3` **is the rule for url that is going to be rewritten**
3. after 2nd rule you can add some redirection type like `[R=301]` **that means it is permanent redirect**

So basicaly your rule is going to produce:
http://domain.com/pagenumber-idnumber-imdefinition
From
http://domain.com/index.php?page=pagenumber&id=idnumber&im=imdefinition

I hope I was clear...

Answer (score 2):

The rule is a so called regular expression where each group is in brackets. The dot is a single random char which can be modified by an asterisk for 0...n times. A plus sign would mean 1...n. If no modifier is added it expects exactly one character.

Not sure if Tim Cooper made a mistake but I'm responding here to the original rewrite rule (`^(.)-(.)-(.*)$`):

That rule takes a URL like: http://example.com/a-b-def and redirects it to: index.php?page=a&id=b&im=def

You should also know that an input with does not have the right pattern will not match so the URL http://example.com/aaa-bb-def would not work.

Comment: Regular expressions are a wide and complex filed where you can find easy more informations on the web. E.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). For the syntax of RewriteRule I read the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule